# Not A Group By Expression Error With Departments and Commissions

Tags: sql, sqlplus

Okay guys here is the question.
I have to list the department ID, department name, count of sales reps, and average commission rate for each department. Also I need to Group by department, and sort by average commission rate in ascending order.

I am receiving an error at line 1 under the De.Dept_ID saying that is not a group by expression

Here is my code:

```
 SELECT DE.Dept_ID as DeptID, Dept_Name as DeptName, COUNT(SR.Sales_Rep_ID) as SalesRepCount,
 Comm_Rate as AvgCommRate  
 FROM DEPT_arb DE, SALES_REP_arb SR, COMMISSION_arb C
 WHERE DE.Dept_ID = SR.Dept_ID AND
 Comm_Rate = (SELECT AVG(Comm_Rate) FROM COMMISSION_arb WHERE SR.Comm_Class = C.Comm_Class)
 GROUP BY Dept_Name
 ORDER BY C.Comm_Rate;
```

I appreciate the input

Comment: Please don't ask the same question twice

Comment: @CharlesBretana Hey Charles, I apologize if this bothers you however I felt that my question changed a bit and I wanted to refresh my question. However since I am new to this site I was not sure how so I made a new question.

Comment: @CharlesBretana do you have any suggestions for my question?

Comment: @user2981579 Please resist the urge to post duplicate questions - it's just increasing the noise on the site and won't help you (in fact, it might get you lots of downvotes and close votes).

Answer (score 0):

You only group by `Dept_Name`, but you also select `Dept_ID`, so you must add that to the `GROUP BY` clause as well.

```
 SELECT DE.Dept_ID as DeptID, Dept_Name as DeptName, COUNT(SR.Sales_Rep_ID) as SalesRepCount,
 Comm_Rate as AvgCommRate  
 FROM DEPT_arb DE, SALES_REP_arb SR, COMMISSION_arb C
 WHERE DE.Dept_ID = SR.Dept_ID AND
 Comm_Rate = (SELECT AVG(Comm_Rate) FROM COMMISSION_arb WHERE SR.Comm_Class = C.Comm_Class)
 GROUP BY DE.Dept_ID, Dept_Name
 ORDER BY C.Comm_Rate;
```

MySQL allows omitting it, but I think it's the only database that does.

Comment: Thanks for the input. It is correct that I need to add Dept_ID, but I get a "column ambiguously defined" error for these. I believe it is because Dept_ID is in more than one table but adding DE.Dept_ID does not help either. Any suggestions?

Comment: You need to add the qualifier in two places - in the `SELECT` list and in the `GROUP BY` clause.